# Loading a MKMapView in a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, mkmapview

This code worked perfect when I was using it directly with the `@IBOutlet var MKMapView` from the story board.

Now I'm trying to load the map with using a `@IBOutlet var UIView` on the Story board then create a `MKMapView` and set it to the `UIView` which this code does but...

My problem lyes with trying to show the users location and drop a pin on the map.  This code just shows a generic map without zooming in on dropped pin or showing users location.

```
class SecondRow: UITableViewCell,MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var eventLocation: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var eventDistance: UILabel!

    //old Linkage through storyboard when everything worked
    //@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

    var pins: [MKAnnotation] = []
     var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

//linked through the storyboard
    @IBOutlet var mView: UIView!

//created and Initialized here in this class
    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!


    func ConstructCell(Event:AppEvent)->Void {

        eventLocation.text = Event.getAddress();
        eventDistance.text = String(Event.getDistance()) + " miles";

        createMap(Event)

    }
```

I Need to Know why this code is not showing the users location and not dropping a pin when I create `mapView` using `mapView = MKMapView()`.

It just shows a generic map zoomed all the way out so I know my linking between my `UIView` and `MKMapView` is working.

```
    func createMap(Event:AppEvent)
    {

        self.mapView = MKMapView()
        self.mapView.delegate = self

        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        let eventPin = MKPointAnnotation();
        pins.append(eventPin)
        if pins.count > 1{
            mapView.removeAnnotations(pins)
        }

        Event.getGeoLocation()
        let coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D =      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Event.getGeoLocation().latitude, Event.getGeoLocation().longitude)
        eventPin.coordinate = coord
        eventPin.title = Event.getTitle()
        mapView.addAnnotation(eventPin)

        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05,0.05)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coord, span: span)

        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

       self.mView.addSubview(self.mapView)
    }

//Destroy the map to free up memory 
    func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = false
        self.mapView.delegate = nil
        self.mapView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.mapView = nil

    }
```

Comment: You do not need to set region or call `startUpdatingLocation`. Once you have set `self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true`, the map view will just show the user location all by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement MKMapViewDelegate`- (nullable MKAnnotationView *)viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation;`

Comment: I believe so.  I'm coding in swift and I believe your answer is in Objective C.  I added the rest of the code for my class so hopefully that helps.